# TODO List for Admin and Workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to make TODO List by the next following:

1. Admin interface for workers (UI for managing workers)
2. Allow workers to login/logout

in fact, I have to define two kinds of users: Admin and Worker.

can someone guide me please?

and how can I use this 'devise'?
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

have I pull it to my library? and what's next?

Comment: Here's a good start: http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding your app is simple,so

You can use boolean column in user table to identify user is worker or Admin,
Depending upon role you can have interface

You can watch [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise) for basic devise integration

Comment: thank you very much! I will try what you suggested me and notify you :)